# Find the vector in 3D that simultaneously satisfy the following conditions

Tags: math, vector, linear-algebra, algebra

Find the vector(s) ⃗ in 3D that simultaneously satisfy the following conditions:

a) ‖⃗ ‖ =

b) ⃗ is perpendicular to the vector 〈, −, 〉

c) ⃗ forms an angle of / with the vector 〈, , 〉

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `w = (x,y,z)`.

Condition (b) says `3x-y = 0`, i.e. `y = 3x`.

Condition (c) means `z = 0⋅x + 0⋅y + 1⋅z = cos(π/3)‖w‖‖(0,0,1)‖ = 0.5⋅10 = 5`.

Condition (a) implies `x^2 + (3x)^2 + 25 = 100`, i.e., `10x^2 = 75` or `x = ±sqrt(7.5)`.

In sum `w = (±sqrt(7.5), ±3⋅sqrt(7.5), 5)`.

Note that there are two solutions, one with `+` and another with `-`.